# Jenkins throw error "Library expected to contain at least one of src or vars directories"

Tags: git, jenkins, shared-libraries

I configured Jenkins shared library with git repo which has a structure:

```
resources
|__ some_files
src
|__ some_files
vars
|__ some_files
```

But i got an error: `"Library expected to contain at least one of src or vars directories"`. What's wrong? I have mandatory directories.

Comment: do you have this directories on the correct branch?

Comment: @smelm , yeah. And I f found the root of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is incorrect exception text: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62961

Comment: You save my day. And it is quite strange that you cannot load ONLY resources this way. It is quite common design pattern to separate shared libraries from e.g. configuration files (e.g. yaml with config for the Kubernetes plugin in my case).

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting the same error but my Library has the correct configuration, and I have Groovy files in my `src` and `vars` directories.

Comment: Something to check is the `Library Path (optional)` which should be empty or `./` unless `vars` and `src` folders are within a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I initially set a relative path in the `library path` configuration which does not work and caused the error. left it blank then used the same folder structure

before:

```
resources
|__ some_files
src
|__ some_files
library/vars
|__ some_files
```

after:

```
resources
|__ some_files
src
|__ some_files
vars
|__ some_files
```

[Jenkins Library Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KlL0.png)